# runOnUiThread: Cant touch the View, Exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I know this has been posted multiple times now, but nothing seemed to fix my problem. I create a Loading Dialog on the UI thread, then start another thread which is doing some networking stuff and via interface, the class gets a callback, when networking is done. The problem is, after its done, i cant remove the loading dialog, even with "runOnUIThread". Here is the code:

```
public void onClickLoginButton (View view) {
    if (!((EditText)findViewById(R.id.textNickname)).getText().toString().isEmpty() &&
            !((EditText)findViewById(R.id.textPassword)).getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        loggingIn = new ProgressDialog(this);
        loggingIn.setTitle("Login");
        loggingIn.setMessage("Wait while logging in...");
        loggingIn.show();

        final LoginInterface callbackInterface = this;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Networking net = new Networking();
                net.Login(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.textNickname)).getText().toString(), ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPassword)).getText().toString(), callbackInterface);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

And this is the function that gets called by the networking stuff, after its done:

```
@Override
public void LoginCallback(final boolean loginSuccess, final boolean isActivated) {
    loggingIn.hide();
    loggingIn = null;

    final Context context = this;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (loginSuccess && isActivated) {
                loggingIn.hide();
                loggingIn = null;
                finish();
            } else if (loginSuccess == false) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Login failed! User/Password wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Login failed! Account not activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

And this is the stack trace:

```
04-17 17:06:11.313  13018-13121/com.assigame.nidhoegger.assigame E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1422
    Process: com.assigame.nidhoegger.assigame, PID: 13018
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6122)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:850)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
            at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8908)
            at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:6036)
            at android.app.Dialog.hide(Dialog.java:299)
            at com.assigame.nidhoegger.assigame.Login.LoginCallback(Login.java:72)
            at com.assigame.nidhoegger.assigame.Networking.Login(Networking.java:134)
            at com.assigame.nidhoegger.assigame.Login$1.run(Login.java:64)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-17 17:06:11.719  13018-13018/com.assigame.nidhoegger.assigame E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.assigame.nidhoegger.assigame.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42284588 G.E..... R......D 0,0-684,324} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:366)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at com.assigame.nidhoegger.assigame.Login.onClickLoginButton(Login.java:56)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: But why do you call `loggingIn.hide();` twice in your method?

Comment: Have you tried posting your first `Runnable` to a `Handler` on a worker thread? I think the problem might have to do with your `Thread` not having all the `MessageQueue` Android stuff.

Comment: Android777 identified the problem - the stack trace is from the first call which is the in callback method rather than the UI thread Runnable, and so illegally on the background thread rather than the UI thread.  Probably a simple oversight when adding the runOnUiThread() mechanism.

Comment: Duh. I apologize... I just did not see it. Thank you very much

Comment: They created AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for these kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `loggingIn.hide()` method twice, and the first time not on the UI thread. Change your code to this:

@Override

```
public void LoginCallback(final boolean loginSuccess, final boolean isActivated) {
    final Context context = this;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (loginSuccess && isActivated) {
                loggingIn.hide();
                loggingIn = null;
                finish();
            } else if (loginSuccess == false) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Login failed! User/Password wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Login failed! Account not activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```